# Show that the extension field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is a field

Tags: field-theory

We just started field extensions and I need to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\{a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6} : a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ is a field.

It's easy for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, by just showing that the multiplicative inverse has the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$, but how can I do it for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. How can I show that the inverse has the form $a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6}$ or is there an easier approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277274/is-mathbbq-sqrt2-sqrt3-the-same-as-mathbbq-sqrt2-sqrt3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @lhf given a link, you can see that  there$\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$.

One can verify that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is a root of the polynomial $p(x)=x^4-10x^2+1$. In fact $p(x)$ is an irreducible (what if not!) polynomial over $\Bbb{Q}$ and  ideal $\left \langle p(x) \right \rangle $ generated by $p(x)$ is a maximal ideal.

You know that possibly,

*$R/M$ is a field $\Leftrightarrow$ $M$ is a maximal ideal.*
Hence
$\Bbb{Q}[x]/\left \langle p(x) \right \rangle$ is a field. and $\Bbb{Q}[x]/\left \langle p(x) \right \rangle\cong \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$.